# JavaFX: Turn off font smoothing

Tags: java, javafx, cleartype, font-smoothing

(There are several similar question, but no answer worked)

I started experimenting with JavaFX (JDK8) and first thing I noticed is a horrible font smoothing. I'm using Windows 8.1 and disabling font smoothing/ClearType OS-wide was one of the first things I did. This is respected by most apps (two notable exceptions being IE and Metro UI stuff), but JavaFX seems to be forcing it.

Here's screenshot illustrating it - code snippet in Eclipse IDE and resulting JavaFX window (code is in Scala, but very readable). They both use the same font, so the difference is obvious.

[image: Issue screenshot]

As you can see, I tried setting

```
System.setProperty("prism.lcdtext", "false")
System.setProperty("prism.subpixeltext", "false")
```

but they seem to have no impact whatsoever.

Any hint or insight on this issue?